# Can I replace do_action with wp_schedule_single_event?

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to make all of my synchronous actions asynchronous. It looks to me like I can replace the do_action call with the wp_schedule_single_event call with the addition of the time parameter. Will this work? If not, what's the simplest way to make this replacement and keep the functionality the same?

```
function register_user() {
    $user = new User();
    do_action('after_register_user', $user);
}
add_action('after_register_user', 'subscribe_to_mailing_list', 1);

function subscribe_to_mailing_list($user) {
    //subscribe user to mailing list
}
```

Replace with:

```
function register_user() {
    $user = new User();
    wp_schedule_single_event(time(), 'after_register_user', array($user));
}
add_action('after_register_user', 'subscribe_to_mailing_list', 1);

function subscribe_to_mailing_list($user) {
    //subscribe user to mailing list
}
```

Comment: What are you want to achieve in this change?

Comment: What I'm hoping to achieve is to not make the user wait for the subscribe_to_mailing_list function to complete before loading the next page. I'd like the function to run in the background after the user has completed registration.